# Angularjs ui bootstrap is-open not working for drop down

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pug

Ok so here is my code of the controller:

`$scope.isopen = false;`

Here is my template file (its in Jade)

```
div(ng-click="isopen = !isopen") {{ isopen }}

div.dropdown(is-open="isopen")
    div.dropdown-toggle Click me
    ul.dropdown-menu
        li Asdf
```

So when I click on the div that initially says false, the drop down menu is just unaffected. Why? This is very frustrating.

The drop down menu works fine when I click on "Click me" itself, but I want to toggle it by using is-open.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: suggest you create a demo in **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)** that replicates problem

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into scope inheritance problem. Try putting `isopen` into an object in the scope and accessing that way.

```
$scope.store = {};
$scope.store.isopen = false;


div.dropdown(is-open="store.isopen")
    div.dropdown-toggle Click me
    ul.dropdown-menu
        li Asdf
```

Comment: Can you make a live demo using Plunker? It will really help people to fix the issue. Are you changing the right variable in the div?  `div(ng-click="store.isopen = !store.isopen")`

Comment: Never mind, had the old version of angular bootstrap. Thanks anyway.